# Tooltip is intially at wrong position in seiyria angular-bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-slider

I used Seiyria angular-bootstrap-slider for range slider, but initially when page loads the tooltip is at wrong position. When it is placed in normal page it is working fine,but in modal it is initially at wrong position, but when I click it will be set.

[image]

Comment: There is an issue filed on the repo somewhere. Call refresh when you initialize the slider so it sets positional data correctly.

Comment: @ Seiyria Sorry,I can't get you,can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: Readers would likely need an [mcve] to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you read the doc

> Position of tooltip, relative to slider. Accepts 'top'/'bottom' for
>   horizontal sliders and 'left'/'right' for vertically orientated
>   sliders. Default positions are 'top' for horizontal and 'right' for
>   vertical slider.

slider of you is horizontal it accepts 'top' or 'bottom'

Comment: normally it is working,when I am placed in modal,then it's not working.